# Spring org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException, Required request part 'file' is not present

Tags: java, spring, web-services, httprequest, multipart

I am trying to send a file to the controller by using it in FormBodyPart, rather than directly sending the file to it. Here is the code for making a collection of files

```
private void addFile(Collection<FormBodyPart> parts, File inputFile, String fileType)
        throws ClassificationException {
    if (inputFile == null) {
        throw new ClassificationException("Null input file provided");
    }
    if (!inputFile.exists()) {
        throw new ClassificationException("Input file not found: " + inputFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    if (fileType != null) {

        String charset = "UTF-8";
        parts.add(new FormBodyPart("file", new FileBody(inputFile, fileType, charset)));

    } else {
        parts.add(new FormBodyPart("file", new FileBody(inputFile, inputFile.getName())));
    }
}
```

Parts collection is an arraylist, which would contain the files.

Here is my code for setting Http Entity

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:9000/upload1");
            MultipartEntity reqEntity1 = new MultipartEntity();
            FormBodyPart part1;
            for (Iterator i$ = parts.iterator(); i$.hasNext(); reqEntity1.addPart(part1)) {
                part1 = (FormBodyPart) i$.next();
                System.out.println(part1.getHeader());
            }

            httppost.setEntity(reqEntity1);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            System.out.println(response);
```

My method declaration of controller is

`String index(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile uploadfile)`

I am getting an error from the server stating

> [400] {"timestamp":1474898550131,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException","message":"Required request part 'file' is not present","path":"/upload1"}

My dispatcher.xml already contains bean of multipartResolver.

I am fairly new to web services and might be doing some kind of silly mistake. Please help me out,thanks in advance

Comment: You should not use `$` in variable names. [Java Language Specification §3.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8): *The `$` sign should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems.*

Comment: Are you sure `parts` is not empty?

Comment: When i am printing parts its showing "[org.apache.http.entity.mime.FormBodyPart@1fb3ebeb]", so i dont think it is empty.

Comment: i did change the name of my variable from i$ to i. its showing the same result.

Answer (score 3):

Verify if you have this items:

```java
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipart = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipart.setMaxUploadSize(3 * 1024 * 1024);
    return multipart;
}

@Bean
@Order(0)
public MultipartFilter multipartFilter() {
    MultipartFilter multipartFilter = new MultipartFilter();
    multipartFilter.setMultipartResolverBeanName("multipartResolver");
    return multipartFilter;
}
```

and in the `applications.properties`:

```
# MULTIPART (MultipartProperties)
spring.http.multipart.enabled=true 
# Enable support of multi-part uploads.
# spring.http.multipart.file-size-threshold=3 # Threshold after which files will be written to disk. Values can use the suffixed "MB" or "KB" to indicate a Megabyte or Kilobyte size.
spring.http.multipart.location= /
# Intermediate location of uploaded files.
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
# Max file size. Values can use the suffixed "MB" or "KB" to indicate a Megabyte or Kilobyte size.
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
# Max request size. Values can use the suffixed "MB" or "KB" to indicate a Megabyte or Kilobyte size.
spring.http.multipart.resolve-lazily=false 
# Whether to resolve the multipart request lazily at the time of file or parameter access.
```

Answer (score -1):

there is a very good example in **spring.io** [Uploading Files](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/).